# iconv does not convert bosnian literals on CentOS, but works on Windows

Tags: php, centos, glibc, iconv, libiconv

CentOS Case:

When on `http://urloment.com/` I post a code snippet of:

```
"ćććć"
```

I will get an output: `Ä`

Like this: **http://urloment.com/TG5vg1eC**

However, when I try the same thing on Windows, it will store the full value in my database table: `"ćććć"`.

On my local Windows XAMPP installation I have `iconv` enabled, and it uses: `libiconv`.
On my remote CentOS server iconv uses: `glibc library`.

---

**I've investigated this already so I am still not ensured: is this iconv issue on CentOS caused by "glibc"?**

Comment: This needs more precise info. Can you show some code? Also what is the input encoding, what encoding is it stored in, etc.

Comment: http://urloment.com/huzTpKC - input encoding is UTF-8, in my meta tag it's set to utf-8, I've encoded my files with UTF-8 Without BOM signature, database and tables are: utf8_general_ci .. what am I missing here?

Comment: anyone? willing to answer/help here?

Comment: My guess would be database connection: [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/q/279170) older versions of mySQL have latin1 as the default connection charset.  Drop the `iconv()`s and make sure the database connection is UTF-8

Comment: that's not the case... Works on windows flawlessly, can't seem to work on Linux's

Comment: How do you know that's not the case? Are you 100% positive you are setting the right connection encoding?

Comment: 1001% I am sure that my SET NAMES is 'utf8' and my files, and my PHP file stream, and my meta tags are all set to UTF-8, also, my tables and their columsn are at: utf8_general_ci collation... just doesn't work @ linuxes